# iPhone - getting unique values from NSArray object

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an `NSArray` formed with objects of a custom class. The class has 3 (city, state, zip) string properties. I would like to get all unique state values from the `array`.

I did read through the `NSPredicate` class but couldn't make much of how to use it in this case. The only examples I could find were for string operations.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The totally simple one liner:

```
NSSet *uniqueStates = [NSSet setWithArray:[myArrayOfCustomObjects valueForKey:@"state"]];
```

The trick is the `valueForKey:` method of `NSArray`.  That will iterate through your array (`myArrayOfCustomObjects`), call the `-state` method on each object, and build an array of the results.  We then create an `NSSet` with the resulting array of states to remove duplicates.

---

Starting with iOS 5 and OS X 10.7, there's a new class that can do this as well: `NSOrderedSet`.  The advantage of an ordered set is that it will remove any duplicates, but also maintain relative order.

```
NSArray *states = [myArrayOfCustomObjects valueForKey:@"state"];
NSOrderedSet *orderedSet = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:states];
NSSet *uniqueStates = [orderedSet set];
```

Comment: While I also like the power of @distinctUnionOfObjects, and hence, the answer user probablyCorey gave, the benefit with this concise approach here in this solution is that ordering is preserved.

Answer (score 136):

Take a look at [keypaths](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-SW7). They are super powerful and I use them instead of NSPredicate classes most of the time. Here is how you would use them in your example...

```
NSArray *uniqueStates;
uniqueStates = [customObjects valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.state"];
```

Note the use of **valueForKeyPath** instead of **valueForKey**.

Here is a more detailed/contrived example...

```
NSDictionary *arnold = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"arnold", @"name", @"california", @"state", nil];
NSDictionary *jimmy = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"jimmy", @"name", @"new york", @"state", nil];
NSDictionary *henry = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"henry", @"name", @"michigan", @"state", nil];
NSDictionary *woz = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"woz", @"name", @"california", @"state", nil];

NSArray *people = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:arnold, jimmy, henry, woz, nil];

NSLog(@"Unique States:\n %@", [people valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.state"]);

// OUTPUT
// Unique States:
// "california",
// "michigan",
// "new york"
```

Comment: Caveat: valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.PROPERTY" does not preserve sort order.

Comment: thanks @RobertAltman, for pointing that out. I guess that saved me some debugging time

Comment: What if the object to key is an array and the value exists on first index of it?

Comment: what If i want to return that dictionary not only the value?

Comment: this approach won't work if you have a custom class. It will work if your array object is a NSDictionary object.

Comment: use `NSOrderedSet` instead of `Set` to preserve order