# Core Data: Find the property of NSEntity Objects in NSMutableSet

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

*How can I efficiently find the attributes of an NSEntity object in a set ?*

I have implemented it this way, but it seems to be inefficient. **Is there a faster, easier, more efficient method of finding the attributes of an NSEntity object in a set**, than this approach?

```
soccerTeamViewController.players = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (GGPlayer *playa in chelsea.players) {
    [soccerTeamViewController.players addObject:playa.name];
}
```

^here chelsea is a GGTeam, it has a set of GGPlayers as a property.

Models:

```
GGTeam:
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableSet *players;

GGPlayer:
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
```

From a first time iOS-er.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do not optimize prematurely. You have no evidence as to whether what you are doing is inefficient or not. If there appears to be a slowdown, use Instruments and figure it out. But don't guess, and especially don't guess in advance.
2. What you're doing is perfectly standard.
3. There is a more *elegant* way, namely to use KVC, as described here:

   [iPhone - getting unique values from NSArray object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439564/iphone-getting-unique-values-from-nsarray-object)

   But I have no reason to think that is more *efficient*.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks. Maybe I'm focusing on the wrong thing (efficiency) instead of focusing on getting the app done. Appreciate the feedback and will take a look at the KVC example. :) @matt